# Cassandra - Parameter responsible for number of partitions

Tags: cassandra

After going through multiple websites, partition key in cassandra is responsible for identifying the node in the cluster where it stores data. But I don't understand on what parameter number of partitions are created(like keyspace responsible for Replication Factor) in cassandra..! or it creates partitions based on murmur3 without being able to specifying partitions explicitly

Thanks in Advance

Comment: after sometime of the post I found below link which takes about the partitions and can specify partitions in cassandra.yaml to define the partition: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureIntro_c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra by default uses [partitioner based on Murmur3 hash](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architecturePartitionerM3P_c.html) that generates values in range from -2^63 to 2^63-1.  Each node in cluster is responsible for particular range of hash values, and data with partition key hashed to values in this range go to that node(s).  I recommend to read [documentation about Cassandra/DSE architecture](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archDataDistributeTOC.html) - it will make things easier to understand.